# Delete from table_name where name = %s; возвращает 0?

Tags: python, postgresql, telegram-bot

Суть: В телеграмме если запускать эту функцию у бота показывает ,что "имя" удалено, в логах ошибок не выдает и т.д
Если писать запрос напрямую в pgadmin то выдает 0 при условии name = %s , если же писать напрямую имя которое я добавлял то строчка успешно удаляется. Но я не понимаю почему не удаляет с bind переменной %s так как в нее попадает имя из (data). Когда я выбираю в боте какое "событие" удалить срабатывает хендлер dp.callbeck_query_handler и прикол в том , что он срабатывает и даже вылазит show_alert Имя-удалена , но из бд не удаляется.
Надеюсь вы поняли логику, не знаю в чем может быть причина , думал может что то с правами , пока не попробовал через pgadmin

Код:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler (lambda x: x.data and x.data.startswith ('del'))
async def callbeck_run (callbeck_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await sqlite_db.sql_delete_command (callbeck_query.data.replace ('del', ''))
    await callbeck_query.answer (text=f' {callbeck_query.data.replace ("del" , "")} удалена. ' , show_alert=True )
```

```
async def sql_delete_command(data):
    cur.execute('DELETE FROM cfc WHERE name= %s', (data, ))
    base.commit()
```

Ps: Коммиты стоят , автокомит тоже пробовал , это Postgres, пробовал bind переменные обрамлять в кавычки «»,’’, и пробовал ? , ничего , лог этих ошибок могу скинуть если нужно будет , спасибо!

Comment: Не ответ, но рекомендую сделать так `@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='del')`. Нет никакого смысла проверять есть ли data у колбека, она будет всегда. Невозможно сделать инлайн кнопку без колбека.

Comment: А как выглядит команда, которую вы отправляете боту, нет ли в ней пробела между `del` и собственно именем? Если есть, то имя у вас получается с пробелом перед ним.